# How to send email notification with Jenkins?

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to send a email when my build failed. I've configured my **System Admin e-mail address** : test@gmail.com and **SMTP server** : smtp.gmail.com.

---

Here's my code in my pipeline :

---

```
pipeline{
agent none
stages{
    stage('test'){
        agent{
            label 'VStest'
        }
        steps{
            script{
                //nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
post{
    always{
        mail to: 'test@gmail.com',
            subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
            body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
        echo "sent"
      }
   }
}
```

---

I'm getting the error :

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

---

Someone knows why? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the default SMTP port (25) which will not work with a Gmail account. Try using port 465 for SSL or port 587 for TLS.

This guide might help: http://www.360logica.com/blog/email-notification-in-jenkins/

Comment: I've follow the guide and I'm getting an error at the 'Test configuration' button. If I use the port 456, I'm getting : java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out and with the port 587 : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: Nvm I was using 456 ... my fault